# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' with string concatenation

Tags: python, string, concatenation, typeerror, operands

```
t_c = []
for i in range (10,41,5):
    t_c.append(max("Time"+str(i)+"J") - min("Time"+str(i)+"J"))
```

Whenever I run this code, I get an error

"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'"

Here, Time10J,Time15J,.....,Time40J are numpy data arrays

I tried

```
t_c = []
for i in range (10,41,5):
    t_c.append(max("Time"+str(i)+"J") - min("Time"+str(i)+"J"))
```

and I expected t_c list to be the max minus min value of the numpy ndarray Time10J,....,Time40J

Comment: Why you do max() of a string? max of what?

Comment: I think you mean to `max(eval("Time"+str(i)+"J"))`. As in `Time10J` is a variable name.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't do that I'd put the arrays in a dict instead with the key being the strings.

Comment: @Will max() of strings would be the exicographically largest value.

Comment: @Psytho Time10J is numpy data array. I wanted to make a loop for Time10J, Time15J, Time20J but not strings. from max(), I'm trying to get the max value of Time10J numpy data array not "Time10J" string. How can I do that?

Comment: you should have add the full error trace that ou get, not only one line.

Comment: @MYousefi is right. The [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function is what you're looking for.

Comment: Time10J maybe a data array, but "Time10J" is a string which has nothing to do with your data array.

Answer (score 0):

From MYousefi's comment:

```
t_c = []
for i in range(10,41,5):
    t_c.append(max(eval("Time"+str(i)+"J")) - min(eval("Time"+str(i)+"J")))
```

will produce the result you're after.

However, storing variables like this is maybe not best practice? When you create your series of arrays I think you would benefit from adding them into a dictionary where the keys are your `"Time"+str(i)+"J"` strings.

Depending on the version of python you're using, you could also use f-strings (`f"Time{i}J"`) or .format (`"Time{0}J".format(i)`) to construct the keys.